# unable to install GGTS on STS 4.1.2

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I am unable to install GGTS on STS 4.1.2 with grails-3.3.9.

Can you help?

https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all is 404

Comment: I added below site to my STS - install available software - http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/ but it doesn't show any grails related plugin

Comment: GGTS was discontinued a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

As was already state GGTS was discontinued a while ago. The best alternatively if you can afford it is Intellij Ultimate, however you can also use the community version. The things you lose in the community version are GSP highlighting, and menus for the things the Grails CLI does. You could also still use Eclipse with the Groovy plugin, and whatever plugin they have for Gradle, I think the same could be said for Netbeans.

Comment: Correct, GGTS and the Grails tooling for Eclipse was discontinued a whole while ago and there is no version available that is compatible with the latest Eclipse versions. The Groovy language support from the Eclipse marketplace is up-to-date, but there is no Grails support anymore that I am aware of.